# Getting Error when trying to add new variations with Etsy API V3

Tags: api, etsy

I'm getting the error: "Expected int value for 'property_id' (got NULL)" when trying to add new variations to my Listing, using the EndPoint updateListingInventory.

Note: I get the message error only when trying to add a new variations to a listing,  when I'm editing existing variations the endpoint updateListingInventory works without any problèm.

here is an example of data I send:

```
array:2 [
"products" => array:21 [
     0 => array:3 [
            "sku" => "2020"
            "property_values" => array:4 [
                                 "property_id" => 513
                                 "value_ids" => array:1 [
                                                 0 => 1
                                                 ]
                                 "property_name" => "Size"
                                 "values" => array:1 [
                                             0 => "4x6ft/120x180cm"
                                             ]
                                  ]
            "offerings" => array:3 [
                              "price" => 858.0
                              "quantity" => 100
                              "is_enabled" => true
                              ]
          ]
]
"price_on_property" => array:1 []
```

Although I send the property_id as you notice (513 for custom property), I get the error "Expected int value for 'property_id' (got NULL)".

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

If you need any further pieces of information I'll be happy to share them with you.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,
offrenigs and property_values should be an array of OBJECTS.
for example

```
"offerings" => array:1 [
        0 => array:3 [
          "price" => 858.0
          "quantity" => 100
          "is_enabled" => true
        ]
      ]
```

Best Regards